# Reason for Key Error being returned?

Tags: python

I'm using this Scrabble code to translate letters into numbers, but whenever I try to run it, it returns a Key Error: ' ', and I don't know why this happens or how to fix it.

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}
def tracker():
    word = input("Please enter a word.")
    total = 0
    for i in word:
        total = total + score[i.lower( )]
    print(total)
    return total
def main():
    tracker()
main()
```

Returns the error:

```
Please enter a word. Yellow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Scrabble.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\Scrabble.py", line 14, in main
    tracker()
  File "H:\Scrabble.py", line 10, in tracker
    total = total + score[i.lower( )]
KeyError: ' '
```

Comment: total = total + score[i.lower()] ?

Comment: You entered a space as input...

Comment: `i` is a space, and you don't have a space in your dictionary. One option would be to use `score.get(i.lower(), 0)` to default to a zero score for unknown letters.

Comment: Also, why is `score` in quotes?

Comment: I dont understand why are you using string over a variable?

Comment: @Transhuman No, the spaces in the parens have nothing to do with it, the lexer ignores them.

Comment: For score being in quotes I was just trying a bunch of combinations to get the code to work, the actual code doesn't have it in quotes, yet still doesn't work

Comment: @JeremyKharl Okay, your input has spaces in it, which is used to index into  `scores` which has no key with a space. So, you can either 1) remove those spaces, or 2) use `dict.get` like jonrsharpe said.

Answer (score 0):

Your input probably has a space that is not in the score dictionary. try:

above score

```
unknown_char=0
#Whatever the unknown char data should be
```

in tracker()

```
for i in word:
    try:
        total += score[i.lower()]
    except:
        total += unknown_char
```

Answer (score 0):

In **any** program that requires user's input, you need to manage **input errors**.

I suggest using `.strip()` method on the word you will iterate on. It'll get rid of the spaces. Also, you might want to check if the character is in your dictionnary, I believe you should do as such :

```
if i not in word : raise ValueError("Your error message.")
```

Also, when iterating through your dict, you should use `.items()` (python 3.x) or `.iteritems()` (python 2.7) if you need the key and the value, as such :

```
for key, value in your_dict.iteritems():
```